# How to compare two dates and give condition as per the selected dates on two date Fields in suitelet script?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Here what I am doing is I have just created a simple suitelet as well as linked client script also,
The thing is here I'm getting an error page called unexpected error. I don't know why it is going there. Im providing both scripts please take a look and give me a solution.

```
define(['N/record','N/ui/serverWidget','N/redirect','N/runtime','N/search','N/url'],function(record,serverWidget,redirect,runtime,search,url){
    function onRequest(context){
        var Request = context.request;
        var Response = context.response;
        var name = context.fieldId;
    if(Request.method == 'GET') {
        var form=serverWidget.createForm({title:"Customer entry Suitelet"});
        var primaryinfo=form.addFieldGroup({
            label:'Primary Information',
            id:'custpage_advs_primary_info',
        });
        var firstname=form.addField({
            label:'First Name',
            id:'custpage_advs_first_name',
            type:serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            container:'custpage_advs_primary_info'
        });
        firstname.isMandatory=true;  
        var lastname=form.addField({
            label:'Last Name',
            id:'custpage_advs_last_name',
            type:serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            container:'custpage_advs_primary_info'   
        });
         Response.writePage(form);
        form.clientScriptModulePath = './advs_cs_datefilter.js';
        var fnameValue = Request.parameters.custparam_first_name;
 if(fnameValue){
            firstname.defaultValue =fnameValue;
 var fnamecustomerSearch = search.create({
            type:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
            filters:['custrecord_advs_first_name',"startswith",fnameValue],
        columns:[
        search.createColumn({name: "name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_first_name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_last_name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_email"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_phone"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "internalid"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "id"}),
        search.createColumn({name:"created"})
        ]
        });  
        var counter = 0;
        fnamecustomerSearch.run().each(function(result) {
            log.debug("my result", +result);
            var oldfullname = result.getValue('name');
            var InternalidVal = result.getValue('internalid');
            var firstname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_first_name');
            var lastname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_last_name');
            var email=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_email');
            var phone=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_phone');
            var recordid=result.id;
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
            id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_internalid',
            line: counter,
            value: InternalidVal
            }); 
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
                id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_fullname',
                line: counter,
                value:oldfullname          //....and so on and whatever I'm getting on the search
            });                            // I'm setting those on sublist values on the line
        return true;
        });
    }
     else if(((startDateValue)&&(endDateValue)) &&((endDateValue>startDateValue))){
         startdate.defaultValue =startDateValue;
        enddate.defaultValue=endDateValue;
var datecustomerSearch = search.create({
            type:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',   
            filters:[ 
                ["created","onorafter",startDateValue],
                'or',
               ["created",'onorbefore',endDateValue],
            ],
             columns:[
        search.createColumn({name: "name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_first_name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_last_name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_email"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_phone"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "internalid"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "id"}),
        search.createColumn({name:"created"})
        ] 
        });  
        var counter = 0;
        datecustomerSearch.run().each(function(result) {
        log.debug("my result", +result);
        var oldfullname = result.getValue('name');
        var InternalidVal = result.getValue('internalid');
        var firstname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_first_name');
        var lastname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_last_name');
        var email=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_email');
        var phone=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_phone');
        var recordid=result.id;
        const view_url = url.resolveRecord({
            recordType:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
            recordId: recordid,
            isEditMode: false
        });
    mysublist.setSublistValue({
    id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_internalid',
    line: counter,
    value: InternalidVal
    });
    mysublist.setSublistValue({
        id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_fullname',
        line: counter,
        value:oldfullname
    });
    mysublist.setSublistValue({
        id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_fname',
        line: counter,
        value: firstname
    });                           // I'm doing the same what I did on last condition
        counter++;
        return true;
        });
        }
 else                     // POST part just I'm  creating record & setting the values  and saving
    {
    var Fname= Request.parameters.custpage_advs_first_name;
    var Lname=Request.parameters.custpage_advs_last_name;
    var Email=Request.parameters.custpage_advs_email;
    var Phone=Request.parameters.custpage_advs_phone;
    var Fullname=Fname+' '+Lname;
    
    var customRecord=record.create({
        type:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
        isDynamic:true,
    });
    customRecord.setValue({
        fieldId:'name',
        value:Fullname
    });
 redirect.toSuitelet({
        scriptId: 'customscript_advs_ss_datefilter',
        deploymentId: 'customdeploy_advs_ss_datefilter',
    });
        }
    }
        return{
            onRequest:onRequest
        }
        });
```

here is my client script
here only I had a doubt on how to give condition
**Actually, my need is If we select both dates on as per logically that means**
let me tell scenario

1. #1:START DATE is 09/12/2022 and END DATE is 17/12/2022{//its like Start date is less than end date search should happen as well as it
   has to set the values in the sublist }
2. #2 END DATE IS 17/12/2022 END DATE is 09/12/2022{ // it is like reverse process absolutely there will be no condition  so what I
   have to do is I need to give a pop up prevent user to select date
   like this }

here is my client script and also I'm proving the screenshots of error page and design of my suitelet

```
define(['N/currentRecord','N/search','N/record','N/url','N/format'],function(currentRecord,search,record,url,format){
    function fieldChanged(context) {
        var recordObj=context.currentRecord;
        // var name = context.fieldId;
        
        var startDateValue=recordObj.getValue({
          fieldId:'custpage_advs_start_date'
        });
        var endDateValue=recordObj.getValue({
          fieldId:'custpage_advs_end_date'
        });
        if((startDateValue)&&(endDateValue)){
            var startresponseDate=format.format({
              value:startDateValue,
              type:format.Type.DATE
          });
          var endresponseDate=format.format({
              value:endDateValue,
              type:format.Type.DATE
          });   
          alert("The Customer entry Records that you have entered is between the dates  " +startresponseDate +" and "+endresponseDate  +" Click ok to continue  " );
          var suiteUrl = url.resolveScript({
            scriptId: 'customscript_advs_ss_editviewcolumn',
            deploymentId: 'customdeploy_advs_ss_editviewcolumn',
            returnExternalUrl:false,
            params : {
              custparam_start_date: startresponseDate,
              custparam_end_date: endresponseDate //define a parameter and pass the value to it
          }
          });
        }
        else{
          return true;
        }
      
            setWindowChanged(window,false); 
            window.location = suiteUrl; 
            }
            return{
              fieldChanged:fieldChanged
            }
          });
```

please someone help me to solve my issue

[image: my error page]

[image: before error page it is coming like that]

[image: simple suitelet]

Answer (score 0):

**As far as the dates are concerned** you probably want to get the timestamps by doing something like: `var startresponseDateTs = startresponseDate.getTime();` and then once you have the numbers you can just compare those. *In NS you may be able to literally compare the NS Dates just (date1 > date2) but I'm not 100% about that one.*

**By the way any of these could be causing the unexpected error:*

(1) Your suitelet is missing a bracket above the final return.

(2) all of the "mysublist"'s seem to be undefined. The sublist needs to be created just like you created the form: `var mysublist = form.addSublist({ id: 'custpage_a_sublist_id', type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST, label: 'Hello Sublist' });`

---

*ps. adding a try {} catch(err){} block into the code could help. Not always. If its still not working you're about to get a masterclass in using the debugger :P*

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the client script before/ above the response of suitelet.
and try to add **alert** after a block of code if you don't know how to use **debugger** for each variable as a testing of client script execution.
like:-

```
alert(" startDateValue "+startDateValue);
alert(" endresponseDate"+endresponseDate);
alert("line no 110");      //for line no to get exact line with error.
```

so that you find the line where you are actually getting the error.
Thanks